# Page builder with animation

Tags: wordpress

what is the best plugin to use as a page builder with great animation support in wordpress ?

so I can make modern web design

Answer (score 2):

I've used [VisualComposer](https://visualcomposer.io/) extensively in the past and currently. It has a lot of options in [animation](https://visualcomposer.io/docs/design-options/css-animation/) on the column, row, item level and it doesn't cost too much.

Also, it has a lot of features and plugins that will help you set up a professional looking website in a matter of minutes.

[image]

Comment: after I design with VC can I deliver the site without it or it must be installed ?

Comment: It needs to be installed.